# Why doesn't CFXML like &amp;?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, ampersand

Using CFXML, I'm getting this error:

> An error occured while Parsing an XML document. The entity name must
>   immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

The dump shows ampersands used like this:

> thing-&amp;-things

Here's the code:

```
<cfxml variable="xml">
    <cfoutput>
        <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
            #xml#
        </urlset>
    </cfoutput>
</cfxml>
```

Why doesn't CFXML like this format for ampersands, and what format should they be in?

Comment: Does it need to be double-encoded, e.g. `&amp;amp;` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use xmlFormat() around the data and it should fix your issue.